# Appending results of an element related if function to the last column of a csv

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, if-statement, append

I have been trawling through stack overflow looking for a simple example for appending the results of an if statement as a new column within a csv.

With the example data below I would like to produce a 6th column based on the presence of the word table in column 3 (0 based reference) if column 3 contains table make column 5 (6th column) `"table exists"` however if one does not, make it contain `"No table found"`

#### Example data:

```
title1,title2,title3,Table or no table?,title4
data,text,data,the cat sits on the table,text,data
data,text,data,tables are made of wood,text,data
data,text,data,the cat sits on the television,text,data
data,text,data,the dog chewed the table leg,text,data
data,text,data,random string of words,text,data
data,text,data,table seats 25 people,text,data
data,text,data,I have no idea why I made this example about tables,text,data
data,text,data,,text,data
```

#### Desired output:

```
title1,title2,title3,Table or no table?,title4,Table exists?
data,text,data,the cat sits on the table,text,data,table exists
data,text,data,tables are made of wood,text,data,table exists
data,text,data,the cat sits on the television,text,data,No table found
data,text,data,the dog chewed the table leg,text,data,table exists
data,text,data,random string of words,text,data,No table found
data,text,data,table seats 25 people,text,data,table exists
data,text,data,I have no idea why I made this example about tables,text,data,table exists
data,text,data,,text,data,No table found
```

This could possibly be a very simple task, but I am currently an extreme beginner and this type of code isn't currently in my python repertoire. If you have any help it would be appreciate, thanks GTPE

Comment: Check out the documentation and examples for the CSV module: http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html .  For the case you've described you'll probably want to use DictReader and DictWriter (though that's not the only way, you could do it without using dicts).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quickly you can do something like that:

```
with open("input.csv", "r") as input_file:
    header = input_file.readline()[:-1] #this is to remove trailing '\n'
    header += ",Table exists?"
    output_lines = [header]

    for line in input_file:
         output_lines.append(line[:-1])
         if 'table' in line.split(",")[3]:
             output_lines[-1]+=",table exists"
         else:
             output_lines[-1]+=",No table found"

with open("output.csv", "w") as output_file:
    output_file.write("\n".join(output_lines))
```